# how to create a child page in jboss portal

Tags: jboss, portlet, portal

how to create a child page in jboss portal. 
I have following structure in my *pages-object.xml. I need to create a 2 pages two hold 2 portlets under Home page. Please help me achieve this

```
<deployment>
    <if-exists>overwrite</if-exists>
    <parent-ref>palm</parent-ref>
    <page>
        <page-name>Home</page-name>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>order</name>
                <value>1</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </page>
</deployment>
```

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

To create a sub page you have to add another `deployment` element to the xml file, the `parent-ref` element should contain the concatenation of the parents `parent-ref` and the parents `page-name`, `palm.Home` in your example.

```
<deployment>
  <parent-ref>palm.Home</parent-ref>
  <if-exists>overwrite</if-exists>
  <page>
    <page-name>Child1</page-name>
    <properties>
      <property>
        <name>order</name>
        <value>1</value>
      </property>
    </properties>
    <window>
      <window-name>myWindow</window-name>
      <instance-ref>myPortlet<!--Instance id of your portlet from portlet-instances.xml--></instance-ref>
      <region>myRegion<!--Name of the region in your layout where this portlet should be put--></region>
      <height>1</height>
    </window>
  </page>
</deployment>
```